# Cyrillic (windows - 1251) characters are not correctly displayied on GitHub

Tags: github

I have a files containing cyrillic (windows - 1251) characters but they are not not properly displayed on GitHub?

[This is how it is how it look for me](https://github.com/anklav24/123/blob/master/Create-New-GitHub-Repositories-From-API-Incorrect.bat)

[image: This is how it is how it look for me]

[This is what I would expect](https://github.com/anklav24/123/blob/master/Create-New-GitHub-Repositories-From-API-Correct.bat)

[image: This is what I would expect]

Magic, I created two files, the difference is one line, but in the first case with the encoding in the file on the github everything is fine, and in the second case where the code is only one line longer, the Cyrillic is not displayed correct .

What could be the reason for this behavior?

[Here](https://github.community/t5/Programming-Help-and-Discussion/I-have-a-problems-with-cyrillic-windows-1251-on-GitHub/m-p/35765#M1378) they told me that the github thinks that the encoding Windows 1252, but the reasons are not clear.

Comment: Check out working-tree-encoding attribute. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: @jessehouwing I try add 
*.bat text working-tree-encoding=Windows-1251
in .git\info\attribute But it doest't works for me.